# Convert native SQL to JPQL with inner join

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, hql, jpql

I have this native SQL request :

```
    SELECT LMC_PARAMETRE.* FROM LMC_PARAMETRE
    INNER JOIN INTERVENTION ON INTERVENTION.ID_INTV = LMC_PARAMETRE.ID_INTV
    INNER JOIN REF_SITE ON INTERVENTION.DID_SITE =REF_SITE.ID_SITE
    WHERE INTERVENTION.DCD_STATUT_INTV = '0' AND REF_SITE.ID_CENT = '097';
```

I like to convert it in jpql but the "ON" key word is not being recognized :

```
    JpaQueryBuilder builder = new JpaQueryBuilder();
    builder.append("SELECT lmp FROM "+LmcParametre.class.getName()+" AS lmp ");
    builder.append("INNER JOIN "+Intervention.class.getName()+" AS intv ON ");
    builder.append("intv.idIntv = lmp.intervention.idIntv ");
    builder.append("INNER JOIN "+Site.class.getName()+" AS site ON ");
    builder.append("intv.didSite = site.idSite ");
    builder.append("WHERE ");
    builder.append(lt("intervention.statutIntv", String.valueOf(constanteInferieurePretACharger)));
    builder.append("site.centre.idCent = "+idCentre);
```

According to the HQL documentation : Joins, in HQL, are done using associations between entities.
However I don't see what this means.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have modeled these entities properly using JPA (including their relations) then all your JPQL would be is: "select lp from LmcParametre lp inner join lp.intervention i inner join i.site s where s.idSite = :idSite and i.statutIntv = :statut".

Assuming you have this JPQL query registered as a named query with your LmcParametre class (using annotation

```
@NamedQueries({ @NamedQuery( name="myQuery", query = "select lp from LmcParametre lp inner join lp.intervention i inner join i.site s where s.idSite = :idSite and i.statutIntv = :statut" ) })
```

then you can create a typed query like this:

```
TypedQuery<LmcParametre> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("myQuery", LmcParametre.class);
query.setParameter("idSite", myIdSite);
query.setParameter("statut", myStatut);
List<LmcParametre> results = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the `ON` clause in JPA joins. To do a `JOIN` in JPA, you need to the mapping betweeen the entities and use this associations in the JPQL query.

So, instead of use:

```
SELECT lmp FROM LmcParametre AS lmp
INNER JOIN Intervention AS intv ON intv.idIntv = lmp.intervention.idIntv
INNER JOIN Site AS site ON intv.didSite = site.idSite
```

You need to use:

```
SELECT lmp FROM LmcParametre lmp
JOIN lmp.interventions intv -- you need the "interventions" mapped (@OneToMany?) in LmcParametre 
JOIN intv.site -- you need the "site" mapped in Intervention
```